# Compute a list with all possible assignments of constants to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm developing a function `func(lvars,lconsts)` that, given a list with all variables in a certain operator and a list
with all constants in the current state, computes a list
with all possible assignments of constants to variables.

```
func(['X','Y'],['a','b'])
```

The expected output:

```
[{'X':'a','Y':'a'},{'X':'b','Y':'a'},{'X':'a','Y':'b'},{'X':'b','Y':'b'}]
```

I tried to use itertools like this:

```
def func(lvars,lconsts):
    return list(itertools.product(lvars, lconsts))
```

but instead of the expected output im getting this:

```
[('X', 'a'), ('X', 'b'), ('Y', 'a'), ('Y', 'b')]
```

Comment: How about passing it into a `dict()` constructor instead of a `list()` constructor?

Comment: See this identical question posted minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013948/every-possible-combination-of-two-lists#comment92931442_53013948

Comment: "I tried to use itertools like this:" What you want to do is generate the possible *sequences of values* for the dicts (i.e. `[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]`) using `itertools.product`, and then make the dicts from them (by using the first element in each tuple as the `X` value and the second element as the `Y` value. That means, you want a product of the `['a','b']` list **with itself**, for as many times as there are elements in the list of keys. After that, it's a straightforward matter of making a dict from the key list with each value tuple.

Comment: Please see the linked duplicates for details.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing it into a dict() constructor instead of a list() constructor?

```
def func(lvars,lconsts):
    return dict(product(lvars, lconsts))
```

Comment: Well, for starters, this will produce a `dict`, but the op wants a `list`